# What does ‘Behold the Coagula’ mean in Get Out?

Tags: plot-explanation, get-out

In the initial video shown to Chris when he’s in the basement, Rose’s grandfather says “Behold the Coagula”, and then it is shown on screen in blue font with a small circular insignia in the bottom right (see photo). What does this mean? I’ve looked around and I can’t seem to find anything clear.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Like the other answer mentioned, **Behold the Coagula** is the cult ran by the Armitage family where black people bodies were transplanted with white brains, such that they could join the black superior physique with the white superior intellect.

The blue insignia at the bottom was the symbol of the Order. I'm not sure it has any specific meaning attached to it.

For completeness' sake, I'm also quoting the [Wiki](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Coagula):

> Headed by the Armitage Family themselves, members of this unusual secret society seek out, kidnap, brainwash, and finally "trade places" with healthy and youthful Afro-Americans via [partial] "transmutation" which is to implant the brains of the members, their old relatives and friends, into the bodies of the far younger and fitter black people.

Answer (score 4):

'Coagula' defined basically means a "congealed mass", so I'm guessing it's a reference to the transplantation procedure (i.e. the merging of separate brain matter, or body parts, into one, and the ensuing entity which results. Hence, the new "species" is referred to as a 'Coagula'.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reference to alchemy written in Latin, not literally "coagulate".

"*SOLVE COAGULA*": breaking down and bringing back together.

> An 1856 depiction of the Sabbatic Goat from *[Dogme et Rituel de la Haute Magie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogme_et_Rituel_de_la_Haute_Magie)* by [Éliphas Lévi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baphomet#cite_note-Introvigne-2) The arms bear the [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) words *SOLVE* (dissolve) and *COAGULA* (coagulate).

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baphomet

Answer (score 0):

> The Order of the Coagula is a secretive evil cult of prospective and wealthy Caucasian buyers and a villainous faction in the 2017 horror/thriller movie Get Out. Founded by Roman Armitage somewhere around the 1940s and headed by the Armitage Family themselves, members of this unusual secret society seek out, kidnap, brainwash, and finally "trade places" with healthy and youthful Afro-Americans via [partial] "transmutation" which is to implant the brains of the members, their old relatives and friends, into the bodies of the far younger and fitter black people.
>
> The Order was founded by Roman after he lost the 1936 Olympics to the famous Jesse Owens. Unable to take his loss seriously, Roman pathetically developed a hatred towards (and obsession with) black people and perfected a process - kidnapping black people in order to brainwash them and to implant the brains of old relatives and friends into the bodies of the far younger and fitter black people. As Roman and his wife Marianne grew old, their son Dean (taking over as the new leader of the Order) and his wife Missy used two black persons named Walter and Georgina as new vessels for the dying Roman and Marianne (with the help from Dean and Missy's daughter Rose). Dean even got his son Jeremy to kidnap another black named Andre Hayworth as a new vessel for an old friend named Logan King.

Ref:  http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Coagula

Comment: Is there anything of your own? It is better to paraphrase or summarise the content than a total copy paste.

Comment: @KrayonCarter whatever you are trying to say here, hardly making sense. Your answer is just copy paste of some other site's work and it's appreciated that you give some input of your own in the answer too